# Remove help_text from django-autocomplete-light m2m field

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I was happy to find this cool library, `django-autocomplete-light` which gave me exactly what I wanted. But I am unable to hide the default help_text.

[image]

Implementation was very simple:

**form.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "field1": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
            "field2": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
        }
```

And in **admin.py**

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

I have tried setting/removing `help_text` in model, but it does not help. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution. The following helped override the help_text. Or remove it at all.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "field1": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
            "field2": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
        }

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["field1"].help_text = "Some help text here."
```